# How to get file name with extension from the URL in an optimum way in PHP?

Tags: php, image, url, filenames

Suppose, I've following URL :
**`http://localhost/project-folder/sub-dir-1/images/products/Moulin_1407822344.jpg`**

Now I want only **Moulin_1407822344.jpg** from the above URL.

How should I get this in short, sweet and optimum way in PHP?

Can someone please help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the basename function.

```
basename('http://localhost/project-folder/sub-dir-1/images/products/Moulin_1407822344.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = "http://localhost/project-folder/sub-dir-1/images/products/Moulin_1407822344.jpg";
$parts = explode('/', $link);

$filename = end($parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pathinfo php function to get the filename from URL

$fileName = pathinfo('path/products/Moulin_1407822344.jpg');

echo $fileName['basename'];

Answer (score 0):

Using basename() should work:

```
$url = "http://localhost/project-folder/sub-dir-1/images/products/Moulin_1407822344.jpg";

echo basename($url);
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/iDC0T3)

Answer (score 0):

You need basename function

```
echo basename("http://localhost/project-folder/sub-dir-1/images/products/Moulin_1407822344.jpg") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$reg = '/(?<=jpg|png|gif|jpeg).*/';
$url = 'https://example.com/2012/12/zoe.jpg?w=600&#038;h=400&#038;crop=1,"; "=""';
$rep = '';
$result = preg_replace($reg, $rep, $url);
$cleanfile = basename($result);
echo $cleanfile;
```

http://devcodepro.com/view/58/14/How-to-get-clean-file-image-name-with-extension-from-the-URL-in-PHP-